# IdleAction=lock no longer works in systemd, correct?

Tags: systemd, logind

Per `logind.conf(5)`, the file has `IdleAction=`, and one of the values it can take is `lock`

I have tried `IdleAction=lock` with `IdleActionSec=1min` (with a view to setting this to `15min` for our organization) but it does nothing.

Did the systemd developers remove this functionality without also removing the documentation from the manpage? or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is correct - at time of writing, `IdleAction=lock` is not implemented. [Bug report has been filed - 16391](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16391)